# Is There A Way To Run Code When The Value Changes In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, containers

Is there a way possible to do code when the target value changes?
Like:

```
mod.t[id].messages
```

In here I have messages that is a holder of objects that contain messages.I want to run my code when the container's values change.Is it possible?

Comment: You can create a self called function to continuously monitor the value change and call a specific function when change is found

Comment: That would be a busy loop, which is usually bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) but its only implemented in gecko and mostly used for debugging purposes.

That said if you don't need IE6 I'd suggest giving a look at [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) which works on all modern browsers.

Also, some people might suggest to bind the value to a DOM element, but you REALLY shouldn't do that.